# Delete an object securely from a multi-threaded program

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, delete-operator

**DISCLAIMER: neither Boost, nor C++11 allowed.**

I've a program, in which I create an instance of `Foo` and I operate with it in a number of threads. Then I want to delete it securely so those threads do not fall into a segmentation fault.

I've added a mutex member to `Foo` and lock it each time a thread function runs. In order different threads do not conflict with each other.

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;
};

void* thread ( void* fooPtr )
{
    Foo* fooPointer = (Foo*) fooPtr;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        if ( fooPointer )
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock ( &fooPointer->mutex );
            /* some code, involving fooPointer */
            pthread_mutex_unlock ( &fooPointer->mutex );
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_exit ( NULL );
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to delete `foo` securely so no errors occur in threads. I've added a destructor to `Foo`:

```
Foo::~Foo()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock ( &mutex );
}
```

Now the object will not be deleted until all threads finish current loop.

The question is: will the mutex be unlocked after an instance is deleted? Will all the threads finish after an instance is deleted? I bet the answer is `no`. So I change the destructor, but now it seems thread-unsafe:

```
Foo::~Foo()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock ( &mutex );
    pthread_mutex_unlock ( &mutex );
}
```

Can the thread function lock the mutex and start operating the instance after `pthread_mutex_unlock ( &mutex );` and BEFORE the object is deleted?

Comment: I know you say 'no boost' but why not have a look at the way `shared_ptr` is implemented. You really want to use reference counting here.

Comment: Does **neither Boost, nor C++11 allowed** really mean that, or "no third-party implementation of shared pointer"? Why don't you write your own, its not that hard (especially if you don't need to cover all scenarios that general implementations try to cover)?

Comment: Apparently you assume that some threads will still try to access the `Foo` object even as it is being deallocated, and even after that. Is there something wrong about the design?

Comment: I'm trying to write my own. And I've faced some problem, described in the topic

Comment: YOu are passing the `Foo` to your thread functions, therefore, why not simply delete the object after all threads have finished running? If not you should write your own version of `shared_ptr` as mentioned above

Comment: Or just... copy the damn header. The boost license allows you to do that (slightly less essential: is ***RAII*** also _not allowed_? Use it for the lock guards)

Comment: Do you know how many threads will exists? if you know it , you may put a barrier , then the last of them will delete the object.

Comment: Why not do a `thread.join()` and after that destroy your `Foo`

Comment: If you look attentively, you'll notice that those threads run indefinitely until an instance exists. And they must exit as soon as the instance is deleted

Comment: Your if(fooPointer) will never work. No one will come and set your fooPointer to NULL just because the foo object is deleted. You can use a weak pointer for that purpose, if somehow your application really requires such a communication between the threads.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to first lock fooPointer->mutex and then check if fooPointer might have been null - also is anything going to set fooPointer to NULL at some point?

Comment: I've asked a simple question: `will the mutex be unlocked after an instance is deleted?` Can some1 answer it please?

Comment: In fact, its state will be undefined since the mutex is already deleted! The problem, is that you have some very very wrong assumptions, and that's why you think you need it to unlock. Even if it unlocks, how does it really help you? If there were a thread waiting for it to be unlocked, it would continue and start operating on a dangling pointer.

Comment: Because you've built a solution around a misunderstanding, and just given what you've done, it's impossible to deduce what you should be doing.

Comment: @enobayram do you understand what my problem is? I want a thread securely exit when an instance is deleted. How is it possible? WITHOUT BOOST.

Comment: The requirement "I want to write code so that it doesn't crash" (my paraphrase) is silly. Code that crashes is broken and incorrect, and it should be self-evident that you are looking for a *correct* solution. It's like asking someone on the street, "what's the correct time?"

Comment: The solution is to implement the boost::shared_ptr and boost::weak_ptr yourself then! Your fooPointer needs to be a weak pointer, end of story.

Comment: I recommend you to go and thoroughly understand what a weak pointer is. You will then immediately realize how it would solve your problem.

Comment: I know this is not asked, but: this is yet another reason for golang to rock!

Comment: Why are these negative questions (req: don't use tool X) even allowed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is missing here is the condition that dictates when thread processing is completed. Deletion of a particular object instance is not a good condition. You havent shown us where the object is deleted. If we could see this in the code, the extra context would be helpful.

What I would suggest is instead of deleting the object, set a flag on the object (bool active() for example). This flag will then be checked by all threads, and when it indicates stop processing, then the threads will stop. Set this flag where you are currently deleting the Foo object. Then once all threads have stopped, delete the Foo object.

If you delete the object and expect to be able to acquire its mutex lock, you will possibly get a crash, or at the least unstable behavior, since the mutex is a member of Foo, and it will be destroyed with the object.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        void lockMutex();
        void unlockMutex();
        // Active should be mutex protected as well
        // Or you could consider using a pthread_rwlock
        bool active() {return active_;}
        void setActive(bool a) {active_ = a;}
    private:
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;
        bool active_;
};

void* thread ( void* fooPtr )
{
    Foo* fooPointer = (Foo*) fooPtr;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        if ( fooPointer->active() )
        {
            fooPointer->lockMutex();
            /* some code, involving fooPointer */
            fooPointer->unlockMutex();
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_exit ( NULL );
        }
    }

    // somewhere else in the code
    fooPointer->setActive(false);
}
```

Foo::setActive(true) must be called either in the constructor, or when the object is created. And the Foo object should be deleted once the threads stop, most likely after pthread_join() has completed.

Comment: Access to `active` needs some way to guarantee visibility of updates.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, good point, it should be mutex protected too.

Comment: This is not the correnct answer in the end. The code just decrease the ratio of crash. Consider the situation: class instance is destructed, but another is still access fooPointer as some reason.

Answer (score 10):

Let's start with the begin of your question:

> I've a program, in which I create an instance of Foo and I operate
>   with it in a number of threads. Then I want to delete it securely so
>   those threads do not fall into a segmentation fault.

You cannot delete an object which is in use. No amount of mutexes will fix that.

> I've added a destructor to Foo

This is only run when `Foo` is being deleted. Its contents don't matter much, though: It's wrong to call the dtor while other threads are still using Foo.

> I want a thread securely exit when an instance is deleted. How is it possible?

Well, that's the correct question. I could write a whole lot of code for you to use, but that code would just be a copy of `boost::weak_ptr`. So, I won't bother. Just take the boost code yourself.

> Boost not allowed.

Then why are you asking on StackOverflow? That's essentially the same license.

Comment: @Kolyunya: And you _still_ say that Boost is not allowed, not even for ideas?

Comment: Boost is allowed for ideas, not for code, the problem is I can't get the idea from the boost code. It's just unreadable... `template<class T> class weak_ptr
{
private:`

    // Borland 5.5.1 specific workarounds
    typedef weak_ptr<T> this_type;

public:

    typedef T element_type;

    weak_ptr(): px(0), pn() // never throws in 1.30+
    {
    }

//  generated copy constructor, assignment, destructor are fine...

#if defined( BOOST_HAS_RVALUE_REFS )

// ... except in C++0x, move disables the implicit copy

    weak_ptr( weak_ptr const & r ): px( r.px ), pn( r.pn ) // never throw
.

Comment: TRWTF is "is allowed for ideas, not for code". Can you spell "NIH syndrome"

Comment: @sehe why are you so aggressive and rude? I mean what does `F` stand for in `TRWTF`. I've mentioned that I can not get anything from the boost code since it's way too complicated for me.

Comment: The F stands for Failure (it's The Real Worse Than Failure). You don't need to understand the boost code, you can just copy it. You can use the [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) tool to extract the parts you want.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes so, you are telling me to use some code, which I do not know how it works? :D

Comment: Yes, I am. All you need to know is the interface (i.e. what it does, not how), which is in the docs.

Comment: No, I can not `just copy some magic code` because I **must** know at least how it works.

Comment: @Kolyunya: Seriously? How far would you take that - do you know (or care) how `pthread_mutex_t` is implemented?

Comment: @Kolyunya: You know which compiler you need to support, so axe anything you don't need. All the Borland 5.5.1 stuff? Are you using it? As you said, no C++11, so no rvalue refs either, so that bit can be cut too. Then there's a lot of documentation on the Boost site, too. More than we can realistically provide here.

Comment: @Kolyunya: Do you understand the small string optimization in your vendors `std::string` implementation? The empty base class trick employed for optimizing memory requirements on some of the std lib's types? No? Thought so. Now, what again was your objection?

Answer (score -1):

your code posted is not right because c++ object is destroyed by steps blow:

```
obj->Foo::~Foo();

free memory //maybe delete if allocated by new
```

so your source is only protoecting the destructor but not the memory free itself.

maybe source code follows could help you, it's simple and crude but I think it can works

```
    class Foo 
    {

       public:
         void dosomething() {}
    };

    template<typename T>
    class Protect
    {   
    public: 
        struct auto_lock {
            auto_lock(pthread_mutex_t& mutex)
                : _mutex(mutex)
            {
                pthread_mutex_lock ( &_mutex );
            }
            ~ auto_lock() 
            {
                pthread_mutex_unlock ( &_mutex );
            }
            pthread_mutex_t& _mutex;
        };

        Protect(T*& p): _p(p) {}
        T* get() { return _p; }

        void lock() { pthread_mutex_lock ( &_mutex ); }
        void unlock() { pthread_mutex_unlock ( &_mutex );}
        pthread_mutex_t& getlock() { return _mutex; }

        void safe_release() { 
            auto_lock l(_mutex);
            if (_p != NULL)  {
                delete _p;
                _p = NULL;
            }
        }
    private:
        T*& _p;
        pthread_mutex_t _mutex;
    };

void* thread ( void* proPtr )
{
    Protect<Foo>* proPointer = (Protect<Foo>*) proPtr;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        Protect<Foo>::auto_lock l(proPointer->getlock());
        Foo* fooPtr = proPointer->get();
        if ( fooPtr )
        {
            fooPtr->dosomething();
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_exit ( NULL );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (Not my downvote). your assumption is wrong. When it's OK to run the dtor, it is so because there are no other users of the object, and therefore of the memory. That means there is no need to "protect" the memory free itself.

Comment: My answer is wrong, I think I didn't understand the whole thing completely. Thanks, MSalters.